# How to create Rails project programmatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, programmatically-created

I'm using Rails 4.0.0.

I am aware of the commands `rails new ...` used to create a Rails project via terminal. Are there methods to do this programmatically?

I want to avoid having code invoke a pop-up terminal as not all users may have Linux.

**Possible Solution**

Programmatially copy existing base Rails project. Write to new directory.

Comment: Yep, just copy a pre-created template.

Comment: Have you read this part about [application templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates)? Might be relevant for you. It does not get rid of the terminal, but it can help to setup a more complex Rails project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same generator the command [`rails new`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb) uses, for example:

```
require 'rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator'
Rails::Generators::AppGenerator.start ['bar', '--skip-bundle']

# Output:
# create  
# create  README.rdoc
# create  Rakefile
# create  config.ru
# create  .gitignore
# ...
```